# How can I add a new Row to a Gridview and remove the buttons from the previous Row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm referring this walkthrough:

http://snipplr.com/view/72801/adding-dynamic-rows-in-gridview-with-dropdownlists-in-aspnet/

and so far it has been really helpful. However, I'm not quite grasping why the row addition repeats the previous one exactly?

My dilemma is that I want a dropbox, or specifically a button, in a column on the first row, but none of the following ones.

The dynamic row creation is essential, hence why I'm using this tutorial, but I'd like to just code a new row that doesn't contain all of dropdowns that appear at first.

The line:
    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count + 1;

makes sense to me, what I'm wondering is why I can't do that to make null or remove the dropboxes from a specific column in my newly created rows?